# Using Merge with Global Temp Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, merge

I am having an issue with a stored procedure.  I am trying to merge data from a table var into a global temp table.  I get an error as soon as I put a table name in after merge.  This is my first time trying to use it.  If I comment out the merge, everything works.

Does anyone recognize where the issue is?

```
USE [MONDAT]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Pickrate]    Script Date: 02/08/2012 16:12:54 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Pickrate]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@ReportDate Date --= getdate
--<@Param2, sysname, @p2> <Datatype_For_Param2, , int> = <Default_Value_For_Param2, , 0>
AS 
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here

-- Create memory tables filled with the data we require to fille the temp table
DECLARE @StartDate DATE
DECLARE @EndDate DATE
DECLARE @TrueReportDate DATE
DECLARE @EmployeeRecords TABLE(EmployeeNumber CHAR(6),  EmployeeName CHAR(30), OriginalHireDate DATE, Deptcode CHAR(6), DeptDesc CHAR(30), TeamNo CHAR(2), PayDate DATE, Hours NUMERIC)
DECLARE @PickSummaries TABLE(EmployeeNumber CHAR(6), PayDate DATE, Lbs NUMERIC, PiecePay NUMERIC, Grade03Lbs NUMERIC, Grade02Lbs NUMERIC, Grade01Lbs NUMERIC)

--drop temp table if it exists
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM tempdb..sysobjects
    WHERE name LIKE '##HoursByDay%')
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE ##HoursByDay
    END

--create temp table
Create table ##HoursByDay (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
                           EmployeeNumber CHAR(6),
                           EmployeeName CHAR(30),
                           OriginalHireDate DATE,
                           DeptCode CHAR(6),
                           DeptDesc CHAR(30),
                           TeamNo CHAR(2),
                           PayDate DATE,
                           DailyPayHours NUMERIC,
                           DailyLbs NUMERIC,
                           DailyPiecePay NUMERIC,
                           DailyLbsPerHour NUMERIC,
                           DailyGrade01Lbs NUMERIC,
                           DailyGrade02Lbs NUMERIC,
                           DailyGrade03Lbs NUMERIC,
                           DailyGrade01Percent NUMERIC,
                           DailyGrade02Percent NUMERIC,
                           DailyGrade03Percent NUMERIC,
                           WeeklyPayHours NUMERIC,
                           WeeklyLbs NUMERIC,
                           WeeklyPiecePay NUMERIC,
                           WeeklyLbsPerHour NUMERIC,
                           WeeklyGrade01Lbs NUMERIC,
                           WeeklyGrade02Lbs NUMERIC,
                           WeeklyGrade03Lbs NUMERIC,
                           WeeklyGrade01Percent NUMERIC,
                           WeeklyGrade02Percent NUMERIC,
                           WeeklyGrade03Percent NUMERIC,
                           WeeklyRank NUMERIC)

-- determine Period Start, Period End and True Report dates
IF @ReportDate = CAST(GetDate() AS DATE)
BEGIN
    SET @TrueReportDate = DATEADD(d, -1, GetDate())
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @TrueReportDate = @ReportDate
END
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(day, - 1 - (DATEPART(dw, @TrueReportDate) + @@DATEFIRST - 1) % 7, @TrueReportDate)                            
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(day, 6 -(DATEPART(dw, @TrueReportDate) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7, @TrueReportDate)


-- fill the memory tables with data
-- Gather data from the time and attendance system
INSERT INTO @EmployeeRecords (EmployeeNumber, EmployeeName, OriginalHireDate, Deptcode, DeptDesc, TeamNo, PayDate, Hours)
SELECT     EZTrack.dbo.hEmployee.EmployeeNumber, MAX(RTRIM(EZTrack.dbo.hEmployee.FirstName) + ' ' + RTRIM(EZTrack.dbo.hEmployee.LastName)) AS Name, MAX(EZTrack.dbo.hEmployee.OriginalHireDate) 
                  AS OriginalHireDate, MAX(EZTrack.dbo.sOrganization.OrgCode) AS Deptcode, MAX(EZTrack.dbo.sOrganization.OrgDesc) AS DeptDesc, MAX(EZTrack.dbo.sOrganization.OrgCode) AS TeamNo, 
                  EZTrack.dbo.tPunch.Chargedate AS PayDate, SUM(CAST(DATEDIFF(mi, EZTrack.dbo.tPunch.ID, EZTrack.dbo.tPunch.OD) AS numeric) / 60) AS Hours
FROM       EZTrack.dbo.tPunch INNER JOIN
                  EZTrack.dbo.hEmployee ON EZTrack.dbo.tPunch.EmployeeID = EZTrack.dbo.hEmployee.EmployeeID INNER JOIN
                  EZTrack.dbo.hEmployeeOrgs AS hEmployeeOrgs_1 ON EZTrack.dbo.hEmployee.EmployeeID = hEmployeeOrgs_1.EmployeeID INNER JOIN
                  EZTrack.dbo.sOrganization AS sOrganization_1 ON hEmployeeOrgs_1.Orglevel2ID = sOrganization_1.OrganizationID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  EZTrack.dbo.sOrganization INNER JOIN
                  EZTrack.dbo.hEmployeeOrgs ON EZTrack.dbo.sOrganization.OrganizationID = EZTrack.dbo.hEmployeeOrgs.Orglevel6ID ON 
                  EZTrack.dbo.hEmployee.EmployeeID = EZTrack.dbo.hEmployeeOrgs.EmployeeID
WHERE     (EZTrack.dbo.hEmployee.Status = 1 and EZTrack.dbo.tPunch.Chargedate >= @StartDate and EZTrack.dbo.tPunch.Chargedate <= @EndDate)
GROUP BY EZTrack.dbo.hEmployee.EmployeeNumber, EZTrack.dbo.tPunch.Chargedate

-- Gather picking data from the harvesting database
INSERT INTO @PickSummaries (EmployeeNumber, PayDate, Lbs, PiecePay, Grade03Lbs, Grade02Lbs, Grade01Lbs)
SELECT      EmployeeID, BackDate AS PayDate, SUM(BoxCapacity) AS Lbs, SUM(Payrate) AS PiecePay, SUM(CASE WHEN Grade = '03' THEN BoxCapacity ELSE 0 END) 
                  AS Grade03Lbs, SUM(CASE WHEN Grade = '02' THEN BoxCapacity ELSE 0 END) AS Grade02Lbs, SUM(CASE WHEN Grade = '01' THEN BoxCapacity ELSE 0 END) 
                  AS Grade01Lbs
FROM        STmush_30_Main.dbo._vTransData
WHERE       BackDate >= @StartDate and BackDate <= @EndDate
GROUP BY EmployeeID, BackDate

----Place the harvester data into the global temp table
INSERT INTO ##HoursByDay (EmployeeNumber,  EmployeeName, OriginalHireDate, DeptCode, DeptDesc, TeamNo, PayDate)
SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeNumber,  EmployeeName, OriginalHireDate, DeptCode, DeptDesc, TeamNo, @TrueReportDate
FROM @EmployeeRecords

---- Merge the values from the hours query to the temp table
--MERGE ##HoursByDay AS [target]
--USING 
--  (SELECT C.EmployeeNumber, SUM(CAST(DATEDIFF(mi, EZTrack.dbo.tPunch.ID, EZTrack.dbo.tPunch.OD) AS numeric) / 60) AS DailyPayHours
--   FROM EZTrack.dbo.tPunch B INNER JOIN EZTrack.dbo.hEmployee C ON EZTrack.dbo.tPunch.EmployeeID = EZTrack.dbo.hEmployee.EmployeeID
--   WHERE B.Chargedate = @TrueReportDate) as [source]
--ON
--  ([target].EmployeeNumber = [source].EmployeeNumber)
--WHEN MATCHED
--  THEN
--      UPDATE SET
--      [target].DailyPayHours = [source].DailyPayHours


RETURN 0
```

END

When  I execute the SP I get an error "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Pickrate, Line 109
Incorrect syntax near '##HoursByDay'."

Comment: Pretty sure the statement before it needs to end with a semi-colon. You should get into the habit of terminating all statements properly because leaving the semi-colon out will eventually be deprecated: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the compatibility level of your database.

I can reproduce this error by setting it to 2000 or 2005. On 2008 once I remove all references to your base tables it works fine (though the `MERGE` statement needs to be terminated with a semi colon.)

Comment: You were correct.  The SP was being run in a SQL 2000 compatible db.  I added the semi colons like everyone suggested.  I prefer them anyway. I have the table set up as a temp table so it can be removed after an external report is run against it.  I am considering putting it into a permanent table and leaving the data in until the next run.

Answer (score 1):

While [the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) doesn't seem to explicitly mention against #temp or ##global temp tables, I've never seen a `MERGE` example that uses them. Perhaps it is because `MERGE ##HoursByDay` should be `MERGE INTO ##HoursByDay`? Perhaps it is because the previous statement is not properly terminated with a semi-colon? Not in a spot where I can test right now but I would try those.

In any case, why don't you use a permanent table? Other than the fact that you don't have to drop it at the end, it achieves the same concurrency and isolation as your ##global temp table. I don't understand what the global temp table buys you here.